# Nginx Rails website and Passenger with multiple ports

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I would like to run two versions of my rails site, one for production and one for development. The production one will listen on port 80 and the development will listen on port 9033. Here are my config server blocks which are located in the same file

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name mywebsite.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;
  root /path/to/public/dir;
}

server {
  listen 9033 default_server;
  server_name mywebsite.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env development;
  root path/to/public/dir;
  passenger_friendly_error_pages on;
}
```

The problem lies in that when I try to connect to the website through my browser, regardless of which port I use I always get the version of the website corresponding to the environment specified in the *first* server block. So in the example I gave above, it'd always serve the production version of my website.

Why is it that the first server block overrides the second, and how can I make it so that I can access either version of my website without going in a manually changing the config files and reloading nginx?

UPDATE:

None of the suggestions were working, even after clearing the browser cache before sending every HTTP request. I changed my server blocks to the following in the hopes of my server returning different version of the website

```
server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name mywebsite.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env production;
 root /home/alex/code/m2m/public/;
}


server {
  listen *:80;
  server_name dev.mywebsite.com;
  passenger_enabled on;
  passenger_app_env development;
  root /home/alex/code/m2m/public/;
  passenger_friendly_error_pages on;
}
```

and then added the following line in my /etc/hosts file

```
my.ip.addr.ess    dev.mywebsite.com
```

But requests to both domains result in only the production version of my website being returned. Note I'm using the default nginx.conf file. Is there a way I can debug my browser (Chrome v40.0.2214.111 (64-bit)) to see if/where my requests are being altered? I'm thinking the problem lies clientside since the advice the commenters have given me seems like it should work.

Comment: Your configurations seems normal, post logs please. If you'll comment first server block is second working fine on 9033 port as development version? Are there any other server blocks?

Comment: When I comment out the first server block, only the development version at port 9033 returns the correct webpage, the production version gets a 404. Here's a pastebin of my logs:

http://pastebin.com/Bk7vFESX

There are no other server blocks.

Comment: Please test, first, removing both `default_server` directives, and second, removing `server_name` from second `server` location.

Comment: Removing the default_server directives causes the production version to port 80 to be served regardless of which server block is first. Removing server directive on second on does nothing.

OK this is the strangest thing. I've been running "sudo nginx -s reload" to update nginx with changed to my websites conf file. I'm finding that if I run the command and find that both port 80 and 9033 direct to prod version, if I wait 10 seconds, run the command again and wait 10 or so seconds, I'll be directed to the dev version of my website! There seems to be something affecting it besides the conf file

Comment: Are you sure anything is OK with your browser cache and all that stuff? Is it clearly acts like you say, and there is no problem on client side?

Answer (score 0):

And if you try this :

```
listen *:80;
```

and

```
listen *:9033;
```

This was my recommendation regarding the question that aims nginx config. 
By putting those listen directives, according to nginx doc, nginx will **first** match ip:port server blocks and then look at server_name directives in server blocks that **matched** IP:port. So if request containing right 'port' end in the wrong environment this has something to do with either the app or the passenger directives.